# Covering Spaces and Fundamental Groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Can somebody tell me if what I did is right? I need to Draw the based cover $\hat{B}\rightarrow B$ such that $\pi_{1}(\hat{B},v)$ corresponds to the subgroup

1. $\langle a^{3}, a^{2}b\rangle$
2. $\langle aaabbb,aaaabbbb\rangle$

Is this correct?

[image]
Thanks

Comment: no it is not correct. in case of pic 1 fundamental group is $<a^3, b^3, ab^-1,b^-1,a>$ similarly 2nd pic's group is also equally complected

Comment: hints!! consider the universal cover of figure 8 and then there do some suitable identification..I hope this will help you to find such spaces then